# Windows Batch Script, delete all files but one

Tags: batch-file

I am having issues with this one. I have been trying all kinds of different methods but this is the closest I got. I am trying to delete all files with a certain file extension in a directory which has multiple sub directories. But I want to keep one file from being deleted.  Below is what I have:

```
For /R "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\DOMStore" %%i in (*.xml) DO if not %%i==10.10.5[1].xml echo del /q %%I`
```

How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `for /r` delivers the full filename to the *metavariable* `%%i` then the match will never be true.

Use `if not %%~nxi==10.10.5[1].xml`

to process just the name and extension.

The *metavariable* is one of the few areas where batch **is** case-sensitive. All references to the *metavariable* must be in the same case.

If the full-filename to be deleted may contain a space (or other separators/poison characters) then the delete target should be `"quoted"`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple way:

1. move your file to any directory you like, (move)
2. delete all files, (del *. * /f)
3. move your file back. (move)